# Removing old content when a template is included in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<?php include "main.php" #this file is supposed to be included after an event occurred ?>

 <!-- this should be deleted after include, also styles scripts and everything in this old-content id-->
         <div id="old-content">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
    some content
        </div>
```

What i tried, i add the below in the old-content div, but jquery is included only in the template `main.php`

```
$("#old-content").empty();
```

> Problem with this, is that files are not actually removed and when i view page source i can see the old content at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) method it takes elements out of the DOM. Use it when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it.

```
$("#old-content").remove();
```

```js
// find elements
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
  $("#banner-message").remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Remove</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try remove()

```
$("#old-content").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

here's how I'd do it:

```
<?php if (file_exists('main.php')) : ?>
    <?php include 'main.php'; ?>

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($)
        {
            $('#old-content').remove()
        })
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

the good thing about this is, if the file doesn't exist, then the soft include warning gets picked up and the code isn't run, whereas just having the code outside a conditional will always run the function and remove the content, even if it isn't included successfully

Comment: where to add that in the template or in the whole page that the template is included?

Comment: @GragasIncoming where you need it - so in the template :) make sure paths are correct to - probably better to move the include inside the conditional - will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think there is conflicting between jquery. So use javascript code like this.

```
var x = document.getElementById("old-content"); 

x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
```